# Can free abelian groups have a basis of infinite element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups

I'm now reading Rotman's 'An Introduction to Algebraic Topology' and confused with the definition of free abelian group.

> Let $B$ be a subset of an (additive) abelian group $F$. Then $F$ is
> free abelian with basis $B$ if the cyclic subgroup $⟨b⟩$ is infinite
> cyclic for each $b \in B$ and $F=\sum\limits_{b \in B} \langle b \rangle$ (direct
> sum).
>
> A free abelian group is thus a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. A
> typical element $x \in F$ has a unique expression $x=\sum{m_b b}$
> where $m_b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and almost all $m_b$ (all but a finite
> number) are zero.

But next in Theorem 4.1(ii):

> Every abelian group G is isomorphic to a quotient group of the form
> $F/R$, where $F$ is a free abelian group.

the proof of it said that:

> For each $x \in G$, choose an infinite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_x$ having
> generator $b_x$, say. It follows that $F = \sum\limits_{x \in G} \mathbb{Z}_x$
> is a free abelian group with basis $B = \{ b_x : x \in G \}$...(The content hereafter is ommited.)

My question is that an abelian group $G$ could be infinite, then the construction of $F$ in this proof should have a basis of infinite elements, as the book said above:

> one can exhibit a free abelian group with a basis of any cardinality
> merely by forming the direct sum of the desired number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

but it seems to contradict with the definition of free abelian group because

> $x=\sum{m_b b}$
> where $m_b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and almost all $m_b$ (all but a finite
> number) are zero

I also looked up Wikipedia and another Algebra textbook, free abelian group should indeed be finitely generated. (I misunderstand the sentence 'every finitely generated abelian group is a direct sum of a free abelian group and a finite group' , sorry. Edited after.)

I dont't know what's going wrong.

(If I limit the elements of the "infinite direct summed free abelian group" to those who have finite nonzero components, then the finite linear combination of them should also have finite nonzero components, but that seems strange and I don't think this should be called a direct sum. )

Comment: The index set can be infinite of the direct sum $\sum_I\Bbb Z$ but any particular element of it is always a finite combination of the generators.

Comment: Or, in other words, what you say "seems strange" in the end *is the right way to interpret what happens*!

Comment: Nowhere in the Wikipedia page (and I doubt also about the Algebra textbook) says that a free abelian group should be finitely generated.

Comment: There is a notion of a "direct product" $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ (notation may vary) of Abelian groups, which is made up of *formal* sums $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$ with $a_i\in A_i$ - where $a_i$ may be nonzero for infinitely many indices $i\in I$. This is a different construction than a direct sum, and results in a, in a sense, much larger group. (However, if $I$ is finite, those two constructions coincide.)